# Switching between 3 30a 120v loads

Tags: electrical, switch

I have one 30A 120V single phase circuit and three 30A 120V single phase loads.  How do I switch between the three, i.e one is on and the other two are off?

Comment: Would it be acceptable for the loads to be cord and plug connected?  If so,  install a 30 ampere receptacle,  and install a 30 ampere cord and plug on each device.  Then simply plug in the device you want to use.

Comment: How about a [30a 3 position rotary switch](https://www.bluesea.com/products/9010/AC_Rotary_Switch_-_OFF_%2B_3_Positions_120V_AC_30A/)? I don't know if this particular switch is rated for use in home wiring, it's from a marine supplier (though it is UL rated).

Comment: If you go with a multiposition switch, make sure it operates as break-before-make.

Comment: I think Johnny has your solution. A little pricey but if it does what you want then it may be worth the price.

Answer (score 1):

The [3 position switch Johnny pointed out](https://www.bluesea.com/products/9010/AC_Rotary_Switch_-_OFF_%2B_3_Positions_120V_AC_30A/) is listed to UL 508 for industrial control devices, so it should be acceptable for switching some general-use receptacles around.  (You'd be creating a tiny industrial control panel under Article 409 of the NEC -- your average junction box + cover combo meets NEMA 1, and there are provisions in the Code for an industrial control panel that's protected by the upstream breaker.)

Answer (score 0):

Can they be prioritized? If so, magnetic motor starters could be used, such that the highest-priority load drops the other two starters out of circuit, and the middle-priority load drops the least-priority load out of circuit. BUT... momentarily, all three COULD be energized at once unless you used break-before-make starters and drove each actual load from its own motor starter.